# Discord.net sending direct message(PM) to the command runner person

Tags: discord.net

So i am working on a Discord bot, and i wanted something like almost every bot uses: when the player typed a command (!help) then it will send him the cmds. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Discord.Net 1.0** it is very simple :

```
await Context.User.SendMessageAsync("Message");
```

---

You can also embed a message  like this :

```
var EB = new EmbedBuilder();
EB.WithTitle("Secret Commands");
EB.WithDescription("!command \n" + "!anothercommand");

await Context.User.SendMessageAsync("", false, EB);
```